# How to write a generic print for vector of vectors using c++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

My Initial implementation approach in .cpp is like the following:

```
using namespace std;
...
template <typename T>
void print2dvector(vector<vector<T> > v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The declaration in .h file is the following

```
template <typename T> void print2dvector(std::vector<std::vector<T> > v);
```

Here is how I use it,

```
print2dvector<int>(vec_of_vec);
```

The compile stage passes, but failed in linking stage. The error is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void print2dvector<int>(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >)", referenced from:
   spiral_matrix_ii_Challenge::Execute() in spiral_matrix_ii.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please let me know if I miss anything conceptually in implementing this.

Comment: is the function in a header or an implementation file?

Comment: [OT]: you may pass vector as const reference to avoid copy.

Comment: @Piotr The function is implemented in a cpp file and defined in a header file.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's a good point to optimize this code, thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking errors means that your template was not instantiated and linker was not able to link the symbols. As @Piotr Skonticki told, the best option to fix this is to implement it in the place of use or in the header file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for more information.

About the code - I'd write it like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void printVector(const T& t) {
    std::copy(t.cbegin(), t.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
}

template<typename T>
void printVectorInVector(const T& t) {
    std::for_each(t.cbegin(), t.cend(), printVector<typename T::value_type>);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b;
    b.push_back(a);
    b.push_back(a);
    printVectorInVector(b);
    return 0;
}
```

I think this is better than your solution because:

1. It does not rely on a iterable collection type (it can be vector, list, or anything that has iterators and stl-like iterator interface).
2. It does not rely on value type - it always gets proper value type from iterable collection (`T::value_type`).
3. It also avoids object copying because it gets it by a const reference.

Comment: That perfectly solves my issue, thanx:)